# EmguCV 343 missing dll "cvextern.dll" when trying to initialize a new Image<>

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

So, I tried to use Mean Shift Segmentation in EmguCV3.4.3 but ended up getting a problem with the missing dll *cvextern*.

I already tried solutions from other posts but didn't get closer to solving the problem. I tried to set the targeted platform to x64. Someone had posted a list of the dlls that *cvextern* is refering to and there were actually some of them missing (*opencv_legacy* and *opencv_gpu*) but I could not find the dlls in the EmguCV files.

Project type Windows Forms

/////////////////////////////

```
Image<Bgra, byte> imgInput = new Image<Bgra, byte>("C:\\the_targeted_file.png");
Image<Bgra, byte> imgOutput = new Image<Bgra, byte>(imgInput.Size);
CudaImage<Bgra, byte> cudaInput = new CudaImage<Bgra, byte>(imgInput);

CudaInvoke.MeanShiftSegmentation(cudaInput, imgOutput, 5, 10, 50, new MCvTermCriteria(0), null);

imageBox2.Image = imgOutput;
imageBox1.Image = imgInput;
```

/////////////////////////////

The error appears at this line:

/////////

```
Image<Bgra, byte> imgInput = new Image<Bgra, byte>("C:\\the_targeted_file.png");
```

/////////

It should display the input picture at the imagebox1 and the MeanShifted picture at the imagebox2 but it doesn't because of the exception for the missing dll.

Answer (score 0):

If everything worked fine before- try to unload a project from solution (project context menu) and load it back (this fixed error during compilation for our solution).

UPDATE:
Also check the versions of DLL in solution package manager (SPM). Even if dll is present and it's version not as expected- dll will not be loaded/used. So try totally delete this package from solution (from SPM), delete it from "packages" solution folder and install it back.

And make sure all your projects in solution (if you have multiple) are using the same version of package.